# Handling negative values with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a data set that lists the date and quantity of future stock of products. Occasionally our demand outstrips our future supply and we wind up with a negative future quantity. I need to factor that future negative quantity into previous supply so we don't compound the problem by overselling our supply.

In the following data set, I need to prepare for demand on 10-19 by applying the negative quantity up the chain until i'm left with a positive quantity:

```
"ID","SKU","DATE","SEASON","QUANTITY"
"1","001","2012-06-22","S12","1656"
"2","001","2012-07-13","F12","1986"
"3","001","2012-07-27","F12","-283"
"4","001","2012-08-17","F12","2718"
"5","001","2012-08-31","F12","-4019"
"6","001","2012-09-14","F12","7212"
"7","001","2012-09-21","F12","782"
"8","001","2012-09-28","F12","2073"
"9","001","2012-10-12","F12","1842"
"10","001","2012-10-19","F12","-12159"
```

I need to get it to this:

```
"ID","SKU","DATE","SEASON","QUANTITY"
"1","001","2012-06-22","S12","1656"
"2","001","2012-07-13","F12","152"
```

I have looked at using a while loop as well as an outer apply but cannot seem to find a way to do this yet. Any help would be much appreciated. This would need to work for sql server 2008 R2.

Here's another example:

```
"1","002","2012-07-13","S12","1980"
"2","002","2012-08-10","F12","-306"
"3","002","2012-09-07","F12","826"
```

Would become:

```
"1","002","2012-07-13","S12","1674"
"3","002","2012-09-07","F12","826"
```

Comment: I'm not able to reconcile your description of your problem with the example you provide... could you double-check it for accuracy, or if it is correct, add some further explanation as to why those are the desired results?  Also, even though it didn't work, it would probably be appreciated if you posted your attempted solution using the `while` loop and `outer apply`.

Comment: In your second example wwhy did an F12 - 306 get pulled from an S12 1980?   (or should the row 2 been S12 instead of F12?)  Seasons appear not to matter only the SKU?

Comment: It's easier to solve this problem if you detail how the numbers on output came to be

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions! I had a bit of difficulty trying to explain the problem. For this purpose, season is really irrelevant. Essentially what i need to do is start with the furthest out date with a negative value, and work back until I have my first positive value. Then to my next furthest out date and work back until I again have a positive value. So for the first example, I start with -12,159 and work back until row 2, which finally gives me a positive value. Ex 2, I incorrectly made it -826 instead of 826. So -306 works back to 1980 giving me 1674.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to get a lot of answers - so here's something if you won't get the right 'how-to do it in pure SQL'. Ignore this solution if there's anything SQLish - it's just a defensive coding, not elegant.

If you want to get a sum of all data with same season why deleting duplicate records - just get it outside, run a foreach loop, sum all data with same season value, update table with the right values and delete unnecessary entries. Here's one of the ways to do it (pseudocode):

```
productsArray = SELECT * FROM products
processed = array (associative)
foreach product in productsArray:
  if product[season] not in processed:
    processed[season] = product[quantity]
    UPDATE products SET quantity = processed[season] WHERE id = product[id]
  else:
    processed[season] = processed[season] + product[quantity]
    DELETE FROM products WHERE id = product[id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `CROSS APPLY` - tested

```
SELECT b.ID,SKU,b.DATE,SEASON,QUANTITY
FROM (
  SELECT SKU,SEASON, SUM(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY
  FROM T1 
  GROUP BY SKU,SEASON
  ) a
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 b.ID,b.Date FROM T1 b
  WHERE a.SKU = b.SKU AND a.SEASON = b.SEASON
  ORDER BY b.ID ASC
  ) b
  ORDER BY ID ASC
```