# processing negative values with sql possibly using loop or apply?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling negative values with sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941047/handling-negative-values-with-sql)

I have a data set that lists the date and quantity of future stock of products. Occasionally our demand outstrips our future supply and we wind up with a negative future quantity. I need to factor that future negative quantity into previous supply so we don't compound the problem by overselling our supply.

In the following data set, I need to prepare for demand on 10-19 by applying the negative quantity up the chain until i'm left with a positive quantity:

```
"ID","SKU","DATE","QUANTITY"
"1","001","2012-06-22","1656"
"2","001","2012-07-13","1986"
"3","001","2012-07-27","-283"
"4","001","2012-08-17","2718"
"5","001","2012-08-31","-4019"
"6","001","2012-09-14","7212"
"7","001","2012-09-21","782"
"8","001","2012-09-28","2073"
"9","001","2012-10-12","1842"
"10","001","2012-10-19","-12159"
```

I need to get it to this:

```
"ID","SKU","DATE","QUANTITY"
"1","001","2012-06-22","1656"
"2","001","2012-07-13","152"
```

I have looked at using a while loop as well as an outer apply but cannot seem to find a way to do this yet. Any help would be much appreciated. This would need to work for sql server 2008 R2.

Here's another example:

```
"1","002","2012-07-13","1980"
"2","002","2012-08-10","-306"
"3","002","2012-09-07","826"
```

Would become:

```
"1","002","2012-07-13","1674"
"3","002","2012-09-07","826"
```

Essentially what i need to do is start with the furthest out date with a negative value, and work back until I have my first positive value. Then to my next furthest out date and work back until I again have a positive value. So for the first example, I start with -12,159 and work back until row 2, which finally gives me a positive value. Ex 2, -306 works back to 1980 giving me 1674.

Comment: What SQL have you already written?  Seems like a simple `GROUP BY` with a `SUM(QUANTITY)` would suffice.

Comment: How is this different from your last question [Handling negative values with sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941047/handling-negative-values-with-sql)? If you have not received the answer you are looking for there I suspect it is because the question is not clear. Edit the current question, do not copy and paste it into a new question with a small paragraph at the end.

Comment: jonnyGold - I don't believe a 'group by' would work since the negative values need to be applied only to the previous rows until a positive value is reached. Tried using a while loop to pull out the negative values and then reinsert them against positive values with earlier dates but it was to complicated. Also tried 'outer apply' and can process the values "down the chain" but not up it.

GarethD - this is the same question and I tried updating it previously but did not receive any further answers. I also suspect my question is not clear enough, but I'm unsure how to make it any simpler.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use 2 outer applies. The first to get the maximum date where the quantity is negative (This could also be done using a window function but it would then need to be in a subquery or Common table expression to reference later). The next outer apply can then sum all the quantities between the current row and the last negative row.

```
SELECT  ID, 
        SKU, 
        Date, 
        CASE WHEN Quantity2 < Quantity THEN Quantity2 ELSE Quantity END [Quantity]
FROM    T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  MAX(Date) [LastNegativeDate]
            FROM    T T1
            WHERE   T1.SKU = T.SKU
            AND     Quantity < 0
        ) LastNegative
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  SUM(Quantity) [Quantity2]
            FROM    T T2
            WHERE   T2.SKU = T.SKU
            AND     T2.Date BETWEEN T.Date AND LastNegativeDate
        ) Quantity
WHERE   CASE WHEN Quantity2 < Quantity THEN Quantity2 ELSE Quantity END > 0
ORDER BY SKU, Date
```

This works for both of the examples you have given: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad650/2

```
ID  SKU     DATE                QUANTITY
1   001     June, 22 2012       1656
2   001     July, 13 2012       152
11  002     July, 13 2012       1674
13  002     September, 07 2012  826
```

Comment: GarethD - This is a huge help. Thank you!! The only thing I noticed, is that for example 1, we wind up with 1808 for row 1 instead of 1656. Looks like the 152 is being applied against it.

Comment: Yep, I noticed that after I posted the answer. I have corrected that but I am not sure if the rules applied to sort it are correct or if they happen to work for the current data.

Comment: Works in most scenarios. Here's one that doesn't - [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb9c9/2/0). Still wind up with -4836 in row 4.

Comment: I made an update to my answer below and it has worked for all your scenarios so far.  The only difference is mine is using cursors and would need to be called from a SPROC.

Comment: @jdelwood Made a change to my where clause. Is [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb9c9/3) the output you would expect? If not can you clarify why. Thanks.

Comment: @GarethD - My hope would be to apply row 4(-4836) against rows 3 & 2 to get (2,'001','20120713',204). I apply against 3 & 2 because they are the first to give me a positive outcome. If row 2 was only 592, then i would add row 1 to the mix as well. Thanks!

Comment: @jdelwood I'm still struggling with your logic, but I've had another go, with what I think should be the results in the column "CumulativeQuantity2". http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb9c9/14

Answer (score 1):

If you want a SPROC approach, here's one.  This has worked for all your scenarios so far.  Here is the data I used:

```
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(1,'001',1656)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(2,'001',1986)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(3,'001',-283)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(4,'001',2718)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(5,'001',-4019)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(6,'001',7212)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(7,'001',782)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(8,'001',2073)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(9,'001',1842)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(10,'001',-12159)

--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(1,'002',1980)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(2,'002',-306)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(3,'002',826)

--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(1,'003',2592)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(2,'003',2592)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(3,'003',2448)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(4,'003',-4836)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(5,'003',1968)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(6,'003',1074)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(7,'003',324)
--INSERT INTO TestQuantity(ID, SKU, Quantity) Values(8,'003',1638)
```

Here is the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE #Results(ID int, SKU varchar(50), Quantity int)

DECLARE @sku as VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE skuCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT SKU FROM TestQuantity WHERE Quantity < 0

OPEN skuCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM skuCursor INTO @sku

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id AS INT
    DECLARE @quantity AS INT
    DECLARE quantityCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT ID, Quantity FROM TestQuantity WHERE SKU=@sku AND ID <= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TestQuantity WHERE SKU=@sku and Quantity < 0) ORDER BY ID DESC

    OPEN quantityCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM quantityCursor
    INTO @id, @quantity

    DECLARE @firstID AS INT = @id
    DECLARE @sum AS INT = -1
    DECLARE @currentID AS INT
    DECLARE @currentQuantity AS INT
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @sum < 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @currentID = ID, @currentQuantity = Quantity FROM TestQuantity WHERE SKU=@sku AND ID=@id - 1
            SET @sum = @currentQuantity + @quantity

            WHILE(@sum < 0)
            BEGIN
                SELECT @currentID = ID, @currentQuantity = Quantity FROM TestQuantity WHERE SKU=@sku AND ID=@currentID - 1
                SET @sum = @currentQuantity + @sum  
            END 
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM quantityCursor
        INTO @id, @quantity 
    END

    INSERT INTO #results(ID, SKU, Quantity)
        SELECT ID, SKU, QUANTITY FROM TestQuantity WHERE ID > @firstID and SKU=@sku
    INSERT INTO #results(ID, SKU, Quantity)
        SELECT ID, SKU, QUANTITY FROM TestQuantity WHERE ID < @currentID and SKU=@sku
    INSERT INTO #results(ID, SKU, Quantity)
        SELECT @currentID, @sku, @sum

    CLOSE quantityCursor
    DEALLOCATE quantityCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM skuCursor INTO @sku 
END 

CLOSE skuCursor
DEALLOCATE skuCursor

SELECT * FROM #results order by sku, id

DROP TABLE #results
```

My results:

```
1   001 1656
2   001 152
1   002 1674
3   002 826
1   003 2592
2   003 204
5   003 1968
6   003 1074
7   003 324
8   003 1638
```

Comment: Josh, thanks! This works great too except that SKU needs to be included as well since the table will include thousands of skus and the calculations will need to be done at that level. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool.  I should just need an outer cursor to run the above for each distinct sku where there's a negative number.  I'll give it a shot and update it when i'm done.

Comment: I updated my answer to take into account the SKU.  I took all 3 of your scenarios and ran them through by inserting all 3 into my test table.  My SKUs were different but I think it still works.  My results are at the bottom.  Hope it helped!